# How to query array[object] structure in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the array[object] schema:

```
var operation = new Schema({
    name:{type:String},
    number:[Number],
});

var Info = new Schema({
    operation:[operation],
});
```

when operation.name='jack';

How to query the condition by Info Schema?

```
 Info.findOne({
    condition
 },function(e,r){

 });
```

Comment: Did you try Info.findOne ({name: something, number: 1})?

Comment: For query 1, you can simply do `Info.findOne({'operation.name': 'jack'}, function(err, results){})` and you should get all info documents having "operation.name" = "jack" in atleast of the element in operations array. Can you please explain second query you need help with in more detail?

Comment: sorry, the second query is wrong description, I have deleted it.